# Aplicação Segura

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que será utilizado no meu trabalho para controle das maquinas, terminei a primeira etapa, agora começou a de testes.
Como na minha maquina eu não utilizo antivírus eu não tive nenhum problema nessa parte, mas ao instalar em uma outra maquina o executável é bloqueado pelo antivírus.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A aplicação monitora o computador e obtêm algumas informações, como ip,acesso ao cmd da maquina,acesso remoto.

Como eu faço para eliminar esse suposto vírus?
Tenho que rever todo o código novamente?
Pois no antivírus da microsoft acusa como Backdoor: Win32/Xiclog.A(Esta ameaça pode dar a um hacker malicioso acesso não autorizado e controle de seu PC.) a ideia do programa é controlar os computadores a distancia.

Answer (score 2):

Leia o que você mesmo escreveu.

> a ideia do programa é controlar os computadores a distancia.

Com mais cuidado agora.

> ### controlar os computadores a distancia.

As suas definições pessoais de vírus **não** foram atualizadas com sucesso.

O seu programa é feito de partes. Uma delas garante controle irrestrito a uma máquina. O que garante que as demais partes não podem ser usadas para capturar texto de campos de senha em navegadores, por exemplo? Ou procurar por imagens e transmití-las para um servidor qualquer? Ou encriptar arquivos contra a vontade do usuário, e só decriptá-los mediante comando remoto? etc., etc., insira o comportamento do malware da vez aqui.

Daí você pensa em algum programa que realmente permite operar um computador através da rede, como o Team Viewer, ou a própria área de trabalho remota do Windows. Nesses casos você "autentica" o seu programa para utilizar uma conta de usuário, e essa conta deve ser "manipulada" em tempo real. O escopo do que você pode fazer dessa forma é muito limitado, mas por isso mesmo mais seguro. Talvez, para alcançar o seu objetivo, você deva estudar a arquitetura desses programas. Daí você pode fazer algo semelhante. Mas isso não é controle remoto.

Outra ideia mais simples: talvez você possa resolver o seu problema com uma arquitetura cliente-servidor. Ao invés de criar um programa ponta-a-ponta para controle remoto, crie serviços que podem ser instalados localmente nas máquinas e que façam determinadas ações dentro de um escopo limitado. Você pode fazer com que esses serviços atendam a requisições sobre vários protocolos de rede. Você também pode compartimentalizar suas funcionalidades por serviço, assim fica fácil controlar a autorização do que cada um pode fazer. Mas isso ainda não é controle remoto, ok?