# App sendo reconhecido como potencialmente perigoso

Tags: c#

Eu costumo copiar os `exe` do caminho:

> C:\Users\Username\source\repos\ChatWinForms\AppName\bin\Debug\AppName.exe

Mas ao enviar ele para meus colegas testarem, o navegador diz que o arquivo costuma ser perigoso e bloqueia. Após manter o arquivo e tentar executar, o Windows Defender bloqueia por padrão avisando que o arquivo pode ser perigoso.

Até ouvi falar que isso é porque o app não foi assinado, mas já usei vários programas sem assinatura e nunca aconteceu isso, só quando realmente era algum tipo de crack, etc... Bem eu sou leigo, posso estar enganado.

Tem uma forma de minimizar esse efeito sem comprar um certificado?

Talvez seja porque meu app usa a rede?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChatWinForms
{

    public partial class ChatWinForms : Form
    {
        private IPAddress address;
        private TcpClient client;
        private StreamWriter writer;
        private StreamReader reader;
        private int tcpPort;
        private System.Media.SoundPlayer newUser = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify Calendar.wav");
        private System.Media.SoundPlayer newMsg = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Windows Unlock.wav");

        private void ConectaServidor()
        {
            try
            {
                address = IPAddress.Parse(serverIp.Text);
                tcpPort = 25565;
                client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(address, tcpPort);
                writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                writer.WriteLine(userInput.Text);
                writer.Flush();
                var response = reader.ReadLine();
                if (response.Substring(0, 2).Contains("01"))
                {
                    DesconectaServidor();
                    MessageBox.Show("Esse usuário já está em uso, tente outro nome.", "Usuário em uso.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                } else
                {
                    msgBox.AppendText(userInput.Text + response.Substring(3) + "\r\n");
                    btnConnect.Text = "Desconectar";
                    btnSend.Enabled = true;
                    msgText.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + e.Message, "Erro ao se conectar com o Servidor Remoto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }
        private void DesconectaServidor()
        {
            reader.Close();
            client.Close();
            msgBox.AppendText("Você foi desconectado..." + "\r\n");
            btnConnect.Text = "Conectar";
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
            msgText.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void EnviaMensagem()
        {
            if (msgText.Lines.Length >= 1)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(msgText.Text);
                writer.Flush();
                msgBox.AppendText("Você diz: " + msgText.Text + "\r\n");
                msgText.Lines = null;
            }
            msgText.Text = "";
        }
        private async void RecebeMensagens()
        {

            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Substring(3)))
                    {
                        if (data.Substring(0, 2).Contains("02"))
                        {
                            newUser.Play();
                        }
                        if (data.Substring(0, 2).Contains("03"))
                        {
                            newMsg.Play();
                        }
                        msgBox.AppendText(data.Substring(3) + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    if (Ex is IOException)
                    {
                        DesconectaServidor();
                    }
                    if(Ex is ObjectDisposedException)
                    {
                        client.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
        }




        public ChatWinForms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnviaMensagem();
        }
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(btnConnect.Text == "Conectar")
            {
                ConectaServidor();
                RecebeMensagens();
            } else
            {
                DesconectaServidor();
            }

        }

        private void msgText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                EnviaMensagem();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: acredito que por não ser um executável popular o antivírus/firewall irá tratar como ameaça, por isso muitos softwares que você baixou talvez não tenha disparado o alerta já que provavelmente fazer parte de uma lista confiável, a saída aqui acredito que seria simplesmente adicionar o seu exe na lista de exclusão do seu Windows Defender: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: Realmente, isso sobre a popularidade faz sentido.

Comment: Quando vc usar TcpClient ou qualquer derivado, voce precisa inserir permisao no firewall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem vários fatores para o Windows considerar um executável como **perigoso**:

### ClickOnce e suas permissões

Executáveis assinados com [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx) deixam permissões de administrador mais fáceis para ser gerenciadas pelo UAC (Controle de Conta de Usuário) do Windows, definindo o que o aplicativo irá usar, e se é necessário a permissão de administrador do computador.

> Implantação do Windows Installer requer permissões administrativas e permite limitado somente a instalação do usuário; ClickOnce implantação permite que os usuários não administrativos instalar e concede somente as permissões de segurança do acesso ao código necessárias ao aplicativo.

Automaticamente, o ClickOnce já é incluído desde a versão 2010 do Microsoft Visual Studio, e é gratuíto.

### Assinatura digital

Para tornar um aplicativo **confiável**, deve-se assinar de duas seguintes maneiras: manifestos ClickOnce e manifestos do executável.

Manifestos do ClickOnce são assinados digitalmente por uma chave. Essa chave é obtida por um repositório, arquivo ou pode-se criar um certificado através do usuário da máquina. Se o mesmo tiver uma licença para desenvolvedor, e estiver logado na conta do Visual Studio, a segurança é maior ainda.

Manifestos do executável são feitos para tornar o executável com um **[nome forte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xwb8f617(v=vs.110).aspx)**. Isso não garante total segurança, mas sim a procedência deste arquivo.

### Informações contidas no executável

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Isso garante apenas as informações básicas sobre o executável. Não garante uma segurança autêntica, mas sim um pouco mais de procedência sobre o mesmo. Estas informações são "blindadas" no executável, portanto, são praticamente impossíveis de serem alteradas.

### Código malicioso

Anti-vírus tem por padrão descompilar e analisar o IL-Code do executável, com sua base de definições, encontrar possíveis códigos "suspeitos". Como por exemplo, existem projetos na internet como o LOIC (aplicativo usado para fazer DoS em redes fracas) tem seu código bloqueado. Mas qualquer mínima alteração no mesmo, pode contornar este bloqueio.

É quase incerto saber a procedência de um vírus e/ou o código do mesmo.

### Da onde veio este arquivo?

Executáveis upados para internet são atribuídos como *Baixado da internet* em sistemas Windows, criando uma **proteção extra** para o usuário, ainda mais se o executável não ter nenhum manifesto, assinatura ou certificado.

Por padrão, nos sistemas Windows isso vêm ativado por quase todos arquivos e pode ser facilmente desativado por arquivo. Segue o exemplo:

Um verificador de MD5 (`md5sum.exe`) baixado [aqui](http://www.etree.org/md5com.html), foi armazenado na minha pasta Downloads. O Google Chrome não encontrou ameaças, nem o Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Marcando a `CheckBox` "Desbloquear" irá deixar o arquivo desprotegido pelo Windows.

### Como contornar isso?

Assine, **compacte para um .zip**, certifique o arquivo e envie através de um *Uploader* conhecido, como o Google Drive, Dropbox ou OneDrive.

Comment: `Assine, compacte para um .zip com MD5, certifique o arquivo e envie através de um Uploader conhecido, como o Google Drive, Dropbox ou OneDrive.` Interessante, eu não tinha pensado nisso, e vendo por esse lado o Google Drive já verifica se tem vírus antes de aceitar. ;)

Comment: Usando o ClickOnce e fazendo essa etapa do "Uploader de confiança" já resolveu o problema, vou deixar a recompensa ativa até o fim do prazo só pra ver se aparecem mais respostas, +1

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o jeito correto de resolver seu problema seria implementando um Setup Project para você repassar para seus stakeholders, mais informações no link a seguir:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx
um exemplo em vídeo do procedimento:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU

Answer (score -5):

Cara não sei exatamente como te explicar, mas recentemente onde eu trabalho tivemos que desenvolver uma ferramenta que fosse similar ao Teamviewer
E mesmo estávamos com o mesmo problema, tivemos que cryptar o arquivo .exe para o antivirus não detectar, isso não é uma forma correta de fazer.

Na época eu lembro de ter lido algo que dizia, quando utilizamos informações de outra maquina sem autenticação básica é considerado vírus.

Segue um print da mensagem na época:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link do meu post com uma pergunta similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208962/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-segura)

Comment: Seu programa ainda será avaliado como malicioso por muitos anti-vírus. O correto é usar evidências e UAC.