# Bitdefender falso positivo ao compilar usando modo Debug Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, antivirus

Tenho uma aplicação que tentei em C# que usar ConfuserEx para tentar dificultar um pouco a decompilação, porém agora o BitDefender reconhece ela como um Trojan, não importa o que eu faça, mude namespace etc... Engraçado que somente no modo Debug ele reconhece como um Trojan, se eu rodar em modo Release ele passa batido, alguém ja teve algum problema parecido?

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação é (desktop, console, web)? Esse problema está acontecendo no ambiente de desenvolvimento, testes ou produção? Essa aplicação é distribuída para apenas um cliente específico ou para vários clientes?

Comment: Desktop, uma aplicação simples para gerar etiquetas ZPL para Zebra, em todas máquinas da empresa que utilizam o BitDefender, até na que eu desenvolvo a aplicação.

Comment: Sim, esse é um problema bastante comum em softwares de prateleira. Especialmente quando ofuscados.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o antivírus BitDefender encontrou algum trecho de código semelhante a um vírus na sua aplicação. Mas os antivírus, de forma geral, não são inteligentes o suficiente para distingui-los de uma aplicação segura.

Nesse caso, eu recomendo a troca do ofuscador por dois motivos:

Primeiro porque, ao compilar a aplicação em modo release e aplicar a ofuscação de código, o ConfuserEx deve estar gerando algum trecho de código que o BitDefender considera suspeito.

Segundo porque o projeto ConfuserEx está morto e não recebe nenhuma atualização desde 2016. A compatibilidade da ferramenta com o **msbuild** parou na versão **14.0 (Visual Studio 2015)** e o **.Net Framework** na versão **4.5**.

Answer (score 1):

O uso de ofuscador torna sua aplicação suspeita porque você está intencionalmente ocultando seu código fonte. Não existe outro propósito para um ofuscador senão esconder a construção de um binário na sua máquina destino.

Além disso, é semanticamente impossível proteger completamente a sua aplicação contra descompilações. Ofuscador só dificulta, assim como Trojans e Crypters. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242724/app-sendo-reconhecido-como-potencialmente-perigoso/243819#243819) eu expliquei o que torna um aplicativo como "potencialmente perigoso" e como você pode contornar isso.

Sobre no Debug ele ser reconhecido como um vírus e no Release não, é pelas sessões onde estão sendo chamados. No Visual Studio, ao você depurar um programa, você inicia ele em um servidor dedicado à depuração do VS, no entanto, um binário externo executa as operações e encaminha os endereços ao executável saída.

Após compilar no Debug, os símbolos gerados também são passados como Debug e tem uma estrutura onde espera o `vscode.exe` estar monitorando (mas não é obrigatório). Em resumo, a arquitetura de compilação varia dos parâmetros do compilador. Isso também é entendido de anti-vírus para anti-vírus. Cada um tem seu algoritmo.